# How to make a SimpleFormController show a form using HTTPS

Tags: java, spring, https, spring-mvc

How is this done? I have a view which in certain conditions I need to display using HTTP and in other cases HTTPS. The controller is using SimpleFormController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller doesn't care about the protocol. Simply make the links / form targets in your .jsp to point to `https://site.com/context/controller` and it will work (provided you have successfully setup https of the servlet container)